# Use Ubuntu laptop as ethernet wifi extender with Xubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, xubuntu

I'm getting a new tower computer soon. I don't have a USB or PCI WiFi card, but my laptop has a WiFi connection, and both the tower and laptop have an Ethernet port. What I want to know is if I can share my WiFi connection with another Xubuntu machine via Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two way to do it, one is using a bridge, and the other is routed with NAT. The latter is easier as Wi-Fi connection tends to not work properly with bridge.
Here's how to do the second one.

1. Run `nm-connection-editor` or open Edit connections...
2. Edit the `Ethernet connection`
3. Switch to `IPv4 Settings` tab
4. Change `Method` to `Shared to other computers`
5. Save the connection

Comment: When I get my computer, I'll test this and report back. I'll make sure to mark as answer if it works!